# Conditional class on <html> element a la boilerplate

Tags: theming

This might be a totally mundane question, but I hope not.

I want to add conditional classes onto the `<html>` element of my theme like boilerplate. I'd like to keep things neat and not complicate my page.tpl.php.

```
<?php
  $htmlvar = 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="' .
    $language->language . '" lang="' .
    $language->language . '" dir="'. $language->dir .'"';
?>

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" <?php print $htmlvar ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" <?php print $htmlvar ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" <?php print $htmlvar ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html <?php print $htmlvar ?>> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Reactions? Suggestions? Taunts?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a great way to do this: Drupal 7 modified [`drupal_add_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) to make adding conditional CSS possible outside the template file, but not for arbitrary HTML.  Drupal 6 doesn't have anything.

In Drupal 6, and for arbitrary conditional HTML, you either need to add the markup directly  to [`page.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/6), or you could create a variable in your theme's implementation of [`template_preprocess_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6) that contains the relevant markup as a string:

#### Drupal 7

```
function foo_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $htmlvar = 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="' .
    $variables['language']->language . '" lang="' .
    $variables['language']->language . '" dir="'. $language->dir .'"';

  $variables['conditional_html'] = '<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"' . $htmlvar . '> <![endif]-->';
  // Concactenate the rest of the conditional HTML here
}
```

Then add `$condtional_html` to the appropriate place in `html.tpl.php`.

#### Drupal 6

```
function foo_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $htmlvar = 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="' .
    $variables['language']->language . '" lang="' .
    $variables['language']->language . '" dir="'. $language->dir .'"';

  $variables['conditional_html'] = '<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"' . $htmlvar . '> <![endif]-->';
  // Concactenate the rest of the conditional HTML here
}
```

Then add `$condtional_html` to the appropriate place in `page.tpl.php`.

---

If you're interested in Drupal 7's conditional CSS handling, you can see Bartik's implementation of [`template_preprocess_html()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) for an example:

```
function bartik_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // ...

  // Add conditional stylesheets for IE
  drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/ie.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('IE' => 'lte IE 7', '!IE' => FALSE), 'preprocess' => FALSE));
  drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/ie6.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('IE' => 'IE 6', '!IE' => FALSE), 'preprocess' => FALSE));
}
```

Comment: I think we might be talking about two different things. My post isn't about loading conditional stylesheets, it's about emulating the technique/hack of adding a simple class onto the html element like boilerplate does. Thanks for the tip on d7's _preprocess_html, I'm not able to use d7 yet but that looks like it would come in handy and is more along the lines of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @ha5bro As I said in my answer, Drupal doesn't have anything in its API to specifically support non-CSS (arbitrary) conditional comments: either you write it manually as you've been doing or you add a string to templates via preprocess hooks. I mention `drupal_add_css()` to reference the places where Drupal *does* support conditional comments in its API.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7's [Zentropy](http://drupal.org/project/zentropy) base theme does this, here is a live demo: http://d7.webdrop.net.br/

That said, and since I'm the theme's lone maintainer, I wouldn't use it as all development efforts have gone towards a Drupal 6 backport, available on [here on github](https://github.com/alexweber/drupal_zentropy).
And also, this functionality was eventually removed from the D6 backport.

Answer (score 1):

Browser class module is the way to go here:

http://drupal.org/project/browserclass

Example :

```
<body class="... chrome chrome11 mac desktop">
...
</body>
```

#### Supported browsers

ie, opera, safari, chrome, netscape, ff, konqueror, dillo, chimera, beonex, aweb, amaya, icab, lynx, galeon, operamini

#### Browser version checking

The module creates version classes.

ie[version], opera[version], chrome[version], safari[version], netscape[version], ff[version], konqueror[version], operamini[version]

#### Supported platforms

win, ipad, ipod, iphone, mac, android, linux, nokia, blackberry, NetBSD, FreeBSD, OpenBSD

#### Mobile detecting

The module checks if the device is mobile and adds "mobile" or "desktop" class.